# Painting inside Swing Timer not working

Tags: java, swing, timer, paint

I never worked with `Timer`s before so my problem is probably stupid one really. My program draws a circle which is red and after random seconds the circle should change its color to green. I just made a swing timer as you can see below in the code. And it enters `actionPerformed()` method but it doesn't change color. Could you help me somehow fix my problem with changing colors?

My code:

```
package igrica;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class ChangingCircle implements ActionListener{

JFrame frame;

Timer timer;
Random r;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChangingCircle gui = new ChangingCircle();
    gui.go();
}

public void go() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}   

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    frame.repaint();
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {


        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);

        Random r = new Random();

        Timer timer = new Timer(r.nextInt(5000) + 1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                System.out.println("Timer out");
                g.setColor(Color.green);
                g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
            } 
        });
        timer.start();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: English tip: don't start every sentence with "So", you are not telling a story.

Comment: I know i shouldn't but I don't know with which word start a sentence. xD

Comment: Just remove "So" and the sentence is fine as it is.

Comment: Okay thanks for advise. I'll try to follow it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's quite the mess in your code. Try this:

```
public class ChangingCircle {

    Color color = Color.RED;
    MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            ChangingCircle gui = new ChangingCircle();
            gui.go();
        });
    }

    public void go() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Random r = new Random();
        Timer timer = new Timer(r.nextInt(5000) + 1000, new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

                System.out.println("Timer");
                color = Color.GREEN;
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private int size = 100, loc = 100;

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(loc, loc, size, size);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

            return new Dimension(size + loc, size + loc);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that the timer only changes the property of the shape to be drawn and then calls `repaint()` to reflect the change. The `paintComponent` is called whenever it is needed, even in quick succession and should return quickly.

**Specific Notes:**

- [Start Swing from the EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).
- Create and start the timer from outside of `paintComponent` since it is called many times and that will create and start many timers.
- You should probably set the timer not to repeat.
- Call `super.paintComponent(g);` as the first thing inside `paintComponent`.
- You seem to have an `ActionListener` that does nothing.

**General tips:**

- Use the `@Override` annotation when applicable.
- Call `pack()` on the frame instead of setting its size manually and `@Override` the `getPreferredSize` method of the component you paint on. Return a meaningful size based on what you draw.
- Use `add(component, location)` and not the other way around (deprecated).
- Don't use fields when local variables will do (`Random r` for example).
- Use uppercase constant names (`Color.RED` instead of `Color.red`).

Comment: Thanks you described it so detaily!

Answer (score 6):

Don't initiate a Timer from within a paintComponent method. This method should be for painting and painting only. Instead start the Timer in your constructor and within your Timer's actionPerromed and call `repaint()`, change the state of a field of the class, and use that information within the paintComponent use that field to draw any new information.

e.g.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ChangingCircle {
    JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChangingCircle gui = new ChangingCircle();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }   

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        frame.repaint();
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        private Random r = new Random();
        private boolean draw = false;

        public MyPanel() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(r.nextInt(5000) + 1000, new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                    draw = true;
                    repaint();
                } 
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (draw) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to call the super's paintComponent method from within your override.

If you need to change colors, give the JPanel a Color field, say called `color` and change it's value from within the Timer, and then call `repaint()`. Again within paintComponent, use the value of that field to draw the oval with. Also in this situation, the Timer **should** repeat, so get rid of `timer.setRepeats(false)` in that situation.

Comment: but what to do if 'll need to constantly change color from ex. red to green and then green to red, will that work also?

Comment: @DomagojSabolic: then in the Timer change the state of a Color field and use that in the paintComponent method.

Comment: I think you have a leftover `actionPerformed` in the main class.

Answer (score 0):

The timer works asynchronously and `paintComponent` finishes before finishing the work of timer.

Comment: But my System.out.println works and prints out every time timer finishes

Comment: in this sample u have a JFrame and a Jpanel, if u add a lot of components this implementation will throw exceptions because when your timer try to make changes to g,in the same time another component will use the same instance of g to repaint

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. `paintComponent` *should / can* finish before the timer starts or perform its action. The issue of asynchronism is irrelevant.